# How do I do nested if statements in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Write a program that will check the answers for the latest test. The program will be given a table answers with the following columns:

`id` - the unique ID of the question;

`correct_answer` - the correct answer to the question, given as a string;

`given_answer` - the answer given to the question, which can be NULL.

Your task is to return the table with a column id and a column checks, where for each answers id the following string should be returned:

`"no answer"` if the `given_answer` is empty;

`"correct"` if the `given_answer` is the same as the `correct_answer`;

`"incorrect"` if the `given_answer` is not empty and is incorrect.

Order the records in the answer table by `id`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testCheck()
    SELECT id, IF (...) AS checks
    FROM answers
    ORDER BY id;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE` rather than `IF` when there are multiple conditions.

```
SELECT id,
    CASE WHEN given_answer IS NULL THEN 'no answer'
         WHEN given_answer = correct_answer THEN 'correct'
         ELSE 'incorrect'
    END as checks
FROM answers
ORDER BY id
```